# Android - SearchView in toolbar not expanding

Tags: android, searchview

I'm trying to add a SearchView in my toolbar, I've added the icon, but when I press it, it's not expanding.

Here's the code:

**main_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.app.try.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchManager searchManager= (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        SearchView searchView=null;
        if (searchItem!=null) {
            Log.d("createOptionMenu","search item not null");
            searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        }

        if (searchView!=null) {
            Log.d("createOptionMenu","search view not null");
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        }else{
            Log.e("createOptionMenu","search view null");
        }



        return true;
    }
```

**(this always shows the log message "search view null")**

AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

        <activity
        android:name=".SearchResultActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_result" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
...
```

**searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="HINTTT" />
```

I've tried multiple options as using the `expandActionView()` or the `setIconified(false)`, but non of those works for me.

Comment: Are you importing correct class. i.e android.support.v7.widget.SearchView in activity? Don't include android.widget.SearchView in activity if you are using appcompat searchVIew.

Comment: @Shubendra I was importing the `andorid.widget.SearchView` instead the `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`, but i've changed it and still not working

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use `MenuItemCompat`

```
mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
```

and for collapsing SearchView use

```
MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchItem);
```

and make sure you have changed `android:actionViewClass` to `app:actionViewClass`

Comment: Tried it, still not working, and the log message still showing that the searchView is null

Comment: use 
app:actionViewClass  instead of android:actionViewClass

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I just solved mine by making a minor tweak. change
 `android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`

to  `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`

Answer (score 0):

as the [docs say](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem#expandActionView()), you have to set the `collapseActionView` (bitwise-OR it with `|ifRoom`) flag for the `showAsAction` attribute in the `menu.xml` file.

Now both `exapandActionView()` and `collapseActionView()` will work.

Answer (score -1):

In MainActivity you have to extends ActionbarActivity

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    appcompat:showAsAction="always"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}
```

}